# Can we get some more off-topic close reasons?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Currently the only options for flagging as off topic are:

- Blatantly off-topic/nothing to do with data science
- Migrate to DS meta

At the very least, we could use a general-purpose "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" option in the migration menu.

It might also be nice, looking ahead, to have a close reason for "help me fit a model to this data" type of questions (or whatever our equivalent of "debug my code" is).

<s>Do we need to wait for pro tem mods to do this?</s>

Now that pro tem mods have arrived, what off-topic close reasons are needed?

Comment: In general, yes. Upto three off-topic reasons can be added/edited by pro tem mods. Migration is discouraged during the early beta period, and hence the reason is not provided.

Comment: why is migration discouraged? the current site would massively benefit from half the qs being shifted to crossvalidated or stackoverflow (or just deleted). The site is currently a joke.

Comment: @Spacedman: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/254929) for some reasons not to migrate. It seems to me that only migrating *to* beta sites is explicitly discouraged, though. If it doesn't belong here, it needs to be closed in one way or another.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's most important to get an option for **migration to Cross Validated/stats.SE**.

There are plenty of examples ([some linked here](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/71/322)) of questions that at least some of the community thinks should be moved to Cross Validated, and [one instance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/105071) I know of where the migration has already occurred. There are [reasons to avoid migrating to beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92997/254929) but I have yet to find a source suggesting migration to *established* sites is discouraged.

---

I think we should have an option for **migration to OpenData.SE**.

We have seen several questions that are *perfect* examples of the type of request that OpenData.SE *exists to fulfill*, e.g.:

- [Where can I download historical market capitalization and daily turnover data for stocks?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/587/322)
- [Publicly available social network datasets/APIs](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/422/322)

The only caveat here is that OpenData.SE has been [in beta for over a year with very low daily questions and views](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data). If there is reason to believe they may not leave beta, it might be prudent to wait and see before migrating new "data request" questions to them.

On the other hand, clearly they need the questions; I would argue that by failing to migrate questions that obviously belong there, we're making life harder for them and being "poor neighbors." I think they've been around long enough that we should consider them to be relatively established, and send them questions that will improve their site while focusing ours on *data science* rather than *data chatter*.

Comment: I definitely agree, I don't understand why meta is the only option.  More options (stackoverflow, stats exchange) should be made available