# Can we get a more direct definition of 'What is Data Science' on help Page?

Tags: discussion

If a question is closed as off-topic, the asker is referred to the [help center](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help) for advice on what is on-topic. But as of now, the *[What topics can I ask about here?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)* help page is somewhat self referential, since it doesn't define *Data Science*.  This [meta answer](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/what-characterises-the-difference-between-data-science-and-statistics) does a decent job.

Should the help page be updated to contain something along those lines, or maybe at least a link to a definition?

Comment: Makes sense :) . Do you also have a definition in mind?  If yes, then go ahead and self-answer here.  We shall then select the best definition and update accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible small addition for the top of the [current page](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that would give some insight to *What is Data Science*:

---

### What topics can I ask about here?

**Data Science Stack Exchange** is a Q&A site for developers, researchers, and anyone else interested in Data Science.

Data Science encompasses machine learning, data mining, and data visualization among other topics. See [here](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/29575) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science) for more exposition on *What is Data Science*.

Please [look around](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer](http://helpcenter/self-answer) your own question.

Examples of questions that are likely to be on-topic for Data Science Stack Exchange:

- Given ...

Comment: I think it's worth noting all three of machine learning, data mining, and data viz are included in the description of Cross Validated : https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @klumbard,thanks for the response. Forgive my ignorance, as I am new here, but why is it *worth* noting this?  What is the relevance?

Comment: The help center should also state topics that can be asked here and not on Cross Validated. It's relevant because without those this site becomes redundant.

Comment: @StephenRauch The relevance of  klumbard's comments is that the datascience website has too much overlap with Cross Validated. Most questions on the datascience website are also on-topic on Cross Validated. It unnecessarily fragments the community. And now there is a third website which also greatly overlaps with both DS and CV: https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't see how those comments have any applicability to this answer or to what is in our help center.  There is no rule that says our scope has to be disjoint from that of other sites, or that our help center has to list only topics that are off-topic on Cross Validated.  On the contrary, our help center should describe what our scope is -- whatever that may be.

Comment: Obviously, our site has some overlap with other sites.  So be it.  That has been debated ad infinitum, but at the moment it is what it is.  The role of *our* help center is to describe what is on-topic *here*.  If you'd like to argue about what our scope *should* be, there are other meta threads where that discussion is appropriate.  This thread is about improving how we *document* what our scope actually *is*, to make that clearer to people coming to this site.